# Forward posted image to WCF Rest Service

Tags: c#, wcf, httpwebrequest

I have a webform application written in C# and what I want to do is after the user submits a HTML form with an image, I send that image to a WCF Rest service also written in C#.
The problem is when I get the image in the web service this is corrupted.

I guess that the problem is that I don't encode the file properly, but after days of reading on internet I haven't found a clue.

**Webform code:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     HttpPostedFile image = Request.Files["imagen"];
     string serverResponse = Send("mywebservice/postimage", "POST", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StreamToString(image.InputStream)));
}
```

**Edit (this way worked)**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     HttpPostedFile image = Request.Files["imagen"];
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
     image.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
     byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
     string serverResponse = Send("mywebservice/postimage", "POST", bytes);
}


public int Send(string url, string method, byte[] data)
{
    string serverResponse = "";
    HttpWebRequest newRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    newRequest.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    newRequest.Method = method;
    newRequest.Timeout = 10000;


    if (newRequest.Method == "POST" || newRequest.Method == "PUT")
    {
        Stream reqStream = newRequest.GetRequestStream();
        reqStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        reqStream.Close();         
    }

    WSMessageEnt wsMessageEnt = new WSMessageEnt();

    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse webResponse;
        webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)newRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        serverResponse = new StreamReader(dataStream).ReadToEnd();

    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {

    }

    return serverResponse;
}

public static string StreamToString(Stream data)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
    string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    reader.Dispose();

    return body;
}
```

**Webservice code:**

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "upload-user-image", Method = "POST")]
public Stream UploadUserImage(Stream streamdata)
{
     System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(streamImagen, true);
     // here I get a format error
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the error message?

Comment: I got it in spanish, but it said something like "Incorrect argument/parameter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly one problem: you're converting a stream of bytes, into a string, then back to a stream of bytes. The image bytes are arbitrary bytes, which may or may not map to a string, and the encoding you're using in one conversion (Encoding.Default) may not be the same as the one used in the other (Encoding.UTF8).

Instead of doing this:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StreamToString(image.InputStream))
```

Try doing something like

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
image.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
```

Or just pass the stream to `Send` and copy it to the request stream.

Comment: Thank you Carlos, it worked! Your other option also seemed to be a good idea!